# How to setPlotSpace in CorePlot dynamically?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm trying to set the range on of my plots dynamically. scaleToFitPlots for all plots sometimes does not give the expected result therefore I'm trying to inspect the plot after that. I compare the (length of the range)/(size of bound(in pixel)) for x and y axis. This way I tried to guess which aspect of plot should be scale up to conform the other. The question is why expanding one axis expands the other one as well? Am I wrong somewhere here?

```
-(void)setPlotSpaceForHostView:(CPTGraphHostingView*)hostView{

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) hostView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:hostView.hostedGraph.allPlots];

CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];

CGRect b = hostView.hostedGraph.bounds;
float xRangeLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:xRange.length] doubleValue];
float yRangeLength = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:yRange.length] doubleValue];

float xAxisBound = b.size.width;
float yAxisBound = b.size.height;

if (xAxisBound == 0 || yAxisBound == 0)
    return;

float xRatio = xRangeLength/xAxisBound;
float yRatio = yRangeLength/yAxisBound;

if (xRatio == 0 || yRatio == 0)
    return;

NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f %f %f",xRangeLength,yRangeLength,xAxisBound,yAxisBound, xRangeLength/xAxisBound,yRangeLength/yAxisBound);

if (xRatio > yRatio){

    //xRatio is bigger so scale is:
    float expandScale = xRatio/yRatio;
    NSLog(@"e1:%f",expandScale);

    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(expandScale)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;

}else if (yRatio > xRatio){

    //yRatio is bigger so scale is:
    float expandScale = yRatio/xRatio;
    NSLog(@"e2:%f",expandScale);

    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(expandScale)];
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;

}else{

    //if equal we dont do anything!
    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`-scaleToFitPlots:` adjusts both plot ranges independently to fit the plot data.

Comment: But when I keep using scaleToFitPlots method (specially with only 1 data is available) the plot and the area become narrow and narrower until all the major ticks come over each other like a single line with a dot showing one data. I can skip scaling when there is 1 or 2 data but is this a normal behavior?

Comment: `-scaleToFitPlots:` computes ranges that exactly enclose all of the plot data. Sometimes that's what you want, but a lot of apps, including many of the Core Plot examples, will expand the computed ranges slightly to leave room for things like plot symbols at the edges. If there is only one data point, don't use `-scaleToFitPlots:`. It will compute plot ranges with zero length.